# How to fix a webview error in android?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to create a simple Android application that is just a webview.  I've been following a tutorial (http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/) but have adapted it to have just a webview instead of a button that opens a webview.

When I include the code, I get an error on the line saying "webview cannot be resolved or is not a field".  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?  Full code is below:

Error where line occurs:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
```

MainActivity.java:

package com.example.myfirstapp;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `setContentView(R.layout.webview)` to `setContentView(R.layout.actvity_main)`, or rename you xml file to `webview.xml`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same using xml or programaticaly as below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //should be activity_main

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);//find id of the view defined in activity_main
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

}
}

                      OR

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    webView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);// webview in mainactivity
    setContentView(webView);// set the webview as the layout 
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are following the example as you said then in the android manifest file remove  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" /> and try to run it.